# How to get return value from function like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, highcharts, return

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json', function (data) {
        console.log(typeof(Highcharts.stockChart));
    
});
```

I want to pass data outside the function,what should I do?

```
d=Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json', function (data) {
        console.log(typeof(Highcharts.stockChart));
                return data
    
});
```

```
function info2(name,age){
    ls=[name,age];
    this.name=name;
    return ls;
    
}
d=info2('mary',20)
```

I tried to return the value like normal function,but it doesnt work in the first code.

Comment: *I tried to return the value like normal function* - it's not a "normal function", it's an ajax call with a callback

Comment: Sorry,I am noob in javascript.I used to write python a lot.I think the return value of a function is passed through return.I dont understand  how to get the return value of this ajax call (what exactly it is,is it a function or somthing else?)

Comment: I also tried to define a global variable like 'var d' and change it inside this function but it doesnt work.

Comment: *return value of a function is passed through return* - yes, but you have to look at *where* that `function` is defined.  `function simple(arg) { return arg; }` vs `function callback(arg) { setTimeout(function() { return arg }, 1); }` - in the 2nd, the `return` is for the *inner* function, there's no `return` for `callback()`.  This is similar to how ajax calls work.